Trying to adjust the secondary y axis on my ggplot2
I am trying to adjust the secondary y axis on this plot for the SST. I want that axis to start at 20 rather than 0 so that visually the SST data points are closer to the average RI data points rather than being right at the top
Plot image here.
ggplot(average_RI_per_month_species, aes(x = factor(month))) +
geom_point(aes(y = avg_RI, color = species, shape = "RI"), size = 3) +
geom_line(aes(y = avg_RI, color = species, linetype = species), size = 1) +
geom_point(aes(y = av_SST / 10, shape = "SST"), color = "black", size = 3, alpha = 0.7) +
geom_line(aes(y = av_SST / 10), color = "black", size = 1, alpha = 0.7) +
scale_y_continuous(
name = "Average RI",
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 10, name = "Average SST (°C)", ) ) +labs(
title = "Monthly Average RI and SST", x = "Month", color = "Species", shape = "Metric",linetype   = "Species") +  scale_x_discrete(labels = month.abb) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("Galapagos" = "blue", "Silky" = "red")) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c("RI" = 16, "SST" = 17)) +  # 16 = filled circle, 17 = filled   triangle
theme_minimal()

I tried adding: breaks = seq(25, max(average_RI_per_month_species$av_SST), by = 5))
But this just removed the 0-20 from the y axis but didnt actually make any of the SST data points move

I believe the way ggplot() is written the secondary axis may only be specified as a transformation of the primary axis values. Meaning you can't directly do what you are asking. I could be wrong but I've come across this before. Hadley cites various reasons for this but it makes the plots difficult to customize when there is a good reason to do so. Perhaps consider dividing the raw data by 10 and just changing the secondary axis labels to reflect the actual data?

Sure, you'd just need to adjust your transformation to add 20 in sec_axis (so that 0 on primary axis becomes 20 on secondary axis), and subtract 20 inside aes() for the secondary series, before the division. That's because the two operations need to be the inverse of each other. The only requirement (see ?sec_axis) is that "All secondary axes must be based on a one-to-one transformation of the primary axes." That does not limit you to them being purely proportional to each other.
So we might have
geom_point(aes(y = (av_SST - 20) / 10, shape = "SST") ....

matched with
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. * 10) + 20, name = "Average SST (°C)") ...

On my own fake data, that transforms this:

into this:


data.frame(month = factor(month.abb, levels = month.abb),
           av_SST = 30  +  sin(1:12),
           avg_RI = 0.5 + 0.5 * cos(1:12))  -> df
           
df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(month))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = avg_RI, shape = "RI"), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = av_SST, shape = "SST"), color = "black", size = 3, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Average RI",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(transform = ~., name = "Average SST (°C)", ) ) 


df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(month))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = avg_RI, shape = "RI"), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = (av_SST - 20) / 10, shape = "SST"), color = "black", size = 3, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Average RI",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. * 10) + 20, name = "Average SST (°C)", ) ) +labs(
      title = "Monthly Average RI and SST", x = "Month", color = "Species", shape = "Metric",linetype   = "Species") 


Adjusting the transformation to add 20 in sec_axis and subtracting 20 inside aes() for the secondary series has worked. Thanks a lot.
